# How to edit palette in an indexed image in GIMP 2.8?

Tags: gimp, palette

I remember in GIMP 2.4 editing palette in an indexed image was as easy as changing the foreground color but I'm a little lost in GIMP 2.8 as there is no Dialog menu. So, I played around a little and found out it was in the colors > Map > Set color map > hit Default > scroll to the top > right click the image palette and bring up the palette editor and I figured out I can't do anything after that. Neither can the palette be edited on click nor can we edit the HTML notations that refer to respective palettes. How can we edit palettes in an indexed image(for this I'm using an indexed image with eight colors).
[image]

Comment: I don't use GIMP so I can't say from experience but [the docs say it is accessible from the colormap dialog](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-indexed-palette-dialog.html) (Windows → Dockable Dialogs → Colormap)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In GIMP 2.8 for an indexed image you can use the [Colormap dialog](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-indexed-palette-dialog.html), which is very simple to activate (see the provided link):

[image: Colormap dialog]

In this dialog the entire palette is shown and you can edit each color by right clicking on it:

[image: right click]

Choosing *Edit color*, a color editor appears:

[image: color editor]

And the effect is immediate:

[image: edited image]

Comment: But how could one delete a color from Gimp's colormap?

Comment: If you want a palette with less colors you can [Convert Image to Indexed Colors](https://docs.gimp.org/2.6/en/gimp-image-convert-indexed.html) choosing a different *maximum number of colors* or you can simply redefine the color to be 'deleted' with another one.

Comment: But simply deleting one of the colors in the palette, say when it's a duplicate?

Comment: You can also select by color using the color to be removed and fill the selection with the one you want to maintain. After this operation you can increase the colors to true colors and return to indexed colors with the exact number of colors needed. But imho is not a problem if you have a palette with unused colors.

Comment: It is a problem to have a palette with unused colors when calling some filter that uses colors among the available palette, including the unwanted ones. The workarounds mentioned here do work, yet an option straight in the indexed palette editor was expected.