# GIMP 'select color' tool - color turns out wrong

Tags: gimp

I have this pixel graphic in which I want to turn blue parts into red. So I use the "select color" tool to select the blue part of the image, drag the brightest red possible onto the selected area and it turns out brown. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thank you and happy holidays!

Comment: Welcome! Can you please a screenshot or more  showing what you are doing ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to edit palette in an indexed image in GIMP 2.8?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/69190/how-to-edit-palette-in-an-indexed-image-in-gimp-2-8): try to edit the palette of your image.

Answer (score 5):

Your image is likely color-indexed (loaded a GIF?) and the colors you want are mapped to the closest color available in the color map.

Convert it to full RGB (`Image>Mode>RGB`).

Answer (score 0):

This was frustrating me forever! When you are in the color picker window, choose the paint palette from the top. You should be able to enter in Hex and RGB from there. Hopefully this helps other people. If that one doesn't work just keep running through the tabs and try the others.[image]