# How do I use GIMP to change the black circle to red in this indexed-color png?

Tags: gimp, image-editing

I have this .png

[image]

These are the image properties from GIMP:

[image: image properties from GIMP]

I want to change the black background of the circle to red using GIMP.

I have tried methods 2 and 3 mentioned in [this](https://www.easytechguides.com/replace-a-color-in-an-image-using-gimp/) guide.

When I try

1. *Colors > Map > Color Exchange*
2. or Bucket fill (*Tools > Selection Tools > By Color Select* followed by *Tools > Selection Tools > Foreground Select* followed by *Bucket fill*)

the result is always a grey background

Color Exchange result:
[image: color-exchange-result]

Bucket fill result:
[image: bucket-fill-result]

I think the challenge is the png's color space is "indexed color". How do I change one of the indexed colors to red? Here is the colormap for the image.

[image: colormap]

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, rowote5656! The palette of your image is composed of gray values. In order to change the colors you can either convert the image to rgb, change the color and re-convert in indexed, or you can simply edit the palette (see [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/69190/how-to-edit-palette-in-an-indexed-image-in-gimp-2-8/69197#69197)).